# Conversion from Byte to ASCII in C

Tags: c, byte

Can anyone suggest means of converting a byte array to ASCII in C?  Or converting byte array to hex and then to ASCII?

[04/02][Edited]: To rephrase it, I wish to convert bytes to hex and store the converted hex values in a data structure. How should go about it?

Regards,
darkie

Comment: An ASCII encoded string **is** a byte array so your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I thought a byte array /was/ an ASCII string, in C.  Could you give examples of the input and output you want?

Comment: Nitpicky: A string **is** a byte array and a byte array **can** be interpreted as string.

Comment: just append 0 to the array and you've got the string

Comment: @Felix, your nitpick is recursive.

Comment: @Nick D: I wanted to point out that a byte array does not have to be a string. Especially with values `< 0` and `> 127`. It can be just an array of bytes like there are arrays of integers, etc. It was meant as comment on Andy's comment. A byte array **is not** a string, it can be interpreted as one, that's a difference.

Comment: @Felix, ok :-) and did you mean `< 32`?

Comment: @Nick D: Depends whether we talk about printable or control characters ;)

Comment: @Felix, indeed, but a byte is either `< 0` or `> 127` depending on the sign (though bytes usually are unsigned) :)

Comment: @Nick D: I like this discussion :)

Comment: @Felix, it's off-topic, I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should take some more care on the formulation of your questions. It is hard to say what you really want to hear. I think you have some binary blob and want it in a human readable form, e.g. to dump it on the screen for debugging. (I know I'm probably misinterpreting you here).

You can use `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%.2x", byte_array[i])` for example to convert a single byte in to the hexadecimal ASCII representation. Here is a function to dump a whole memory region on the screen:

```
void
hexdump(const void *data, int size)
{
    const unsigned char *byte = data;

    while (size > 0)
    {
        size--;
        printf("%.2x ", *byte);
        byte++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you interpret an integer as a `char` in C, you'll get that ASCII character, as long as it's in range.

```
int i = 97;
char c = i;

printf("The character of %d is %c\n", i, c);
```

Prints:

```
The character of 97 is a
```

Note that no error checking is done - I assume `0 <= i < 128` (ASCII range).

Otherwise, an array of byte values can be directly interpreted as an ASCII string:

```
char bytes[] = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 0};

printf("The string: %s\n", bytes);
```

Prints:

```
The string: abcde
```

Note the last byte: 0, it's required to terminate the string properly. You can use `bytes` as any other C string, copy from it, append it to other strings, traverse it, print it, etc.

Comment: The integer does not have to be `0 <= i < 128` or (`32 <= i < 128` for printable chars). If you convert an integer to a character, the integer is truncated to the 8 LSBs (least significant bits). Only those have to be in the range. E.g. `i = 1121` gives the same result as `i = 97` (`1121 = 1024 + 97`)

Comment: @Felix: true, but then it doesn't make much sense since you get the modulo 256 of the `int`, which is unlikely to be the desire of the programmer.

Comment: Nitpick: `'a'` may or may not be 97 in C.  On most computers today, it is, but the C standard doesn't guarantee this.  To do this portably, one has to make a lookup table.  Of course, `'a' == 97` is true on most of the systems today.

Comment: Hi, I meant how I can convert bytes to ASCII and store those values, maybe in an array?

Comment: @darkie15: I don't understand what you mean by that. Care to elaborate (or maybe update the question with an example)??

Comment: Okie ... Now hex form can be achieved by using %x format. But this is only for printing .. I want to store that hex form, say in a array .. so i can use it later for more processing.

Comment: @darkie15: how about `sprintf` (or `snprintf` then?

Answer (score 0):

Char.s and Int.s are stored in binary in C. And can generally be used in place of each other when working in the ASCII range.

```
int i = 0x61;
char x = i;

fprintf( stdout, "%c", x );
```

that should print 'a' to the screen.

Comment: Do you want to say that characters are integers?

Comment: Actually no I don't because that is wrong, they are not. They are generally of different size (byte versus word) however you can treat characters as if they were integers and vice versa.