# How can I convert a stream into a string to write to a logfile in C?

Tags: c

Reading from a socket (using epoll):

```
// Message to record what was input/output
char message[255]; // Leave the last four chars for '\n\0'

....  

// Determine where to read from and where to write to
read_from_socket = evlist[j].data.fd;
write_to_socket = epoll_fd_pairs[read_from_socket];

// Handle read/write
nwrite = 0;
while(nwrite != -1 && (nread = read(read_from_socket,buffer,BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0){
    total = 0;
    do{
        // Append to message buffer
        if((nwrite = write(write_to_socket,buffer+total,nread-total)) == -1){
            // TODO: Convert the byte into an ASCii character and append to the message
            // strcat(message,&nwrite);
            break;
        }
        total += nwrite;
        // Keep reading from the buffer until it is done
    }while(total < nread);
}
```

I want to capture the first 253 characters of the input as a string and pass it to a function I have for writing to a log file.  The function call works fine.  The parameter for the function call is:

`void write_to_log(char *write_sentence);`

Comment: Aside: looking at the code comment `// Leave the last four chars for '\n\0'` they do not take 4 bytes, only 2.

Comment: Unless he literally means the four-character sequence '\\', 'n', '\\', '0', though that seems unlikely.  I wouldn't even mention it if he hadn't commented that space for four characters was required.

Comment: By "Convert the byte into an ASCii character" do you mean to convert each byte to Hex ? If yes take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565782/conversion-from-byte-to-ascii-in-c/2566664#2566664

Answer (score 0):

Use `memcpy()` to copy from `buffer` to `message`, and then add the null terminator to it so you can call `write_to_log()`.

```
while(nwrite != -1 && (nread = read(read_from_socket,buffer,BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0){
    total = 0;
    memcpy(message, buffer, nread);
    message[nread] = '\n';
    message[nread+1] = '\0';
    write_to_log(message);
    do{
        // Append to message buffer
        if((nwrite = write(write_to_socket,buffer+total,nread-total)) == -1){
            // TODO: Convert the byte into an ASCii character and append to the message
            // strcat(message,&nwrite);
            break;
        }
        total += nwrite;
        // Keep reading from the buffer until it is done
    }while(total < nread);
}
```

I'm assuming that `BUFFER_SIZE` is less than `253`, so there will always be enough room.  You should probably declare it so that it's always large enough:

```
char message[BUFFER_SIZE + 2];
```

Comment: Or under some circumstances, he might be able to plan on adding a terminator directly to the buffer, and passing it itself to his log function.